# create symlink to another machine

Tags: linux, filesystems, symbolic-link

I have 2 machines. Both running CentOS. Box1 is webserver with apache, php. Box2 is mysql, and file storage. The files will only be accessible from Box1 within the webapp.

I'd like to somehow create a symlink or somesuch on box1 to a folder on box2 where uploaded files can be stored and retrieved. Security in mind, what would be the best way to go about linking these 2 boxes up in a transparent (to apache) way?

NB: the boxes are connected directly to each other via a crossover cable; no lan access to box2.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to run NFS on box2, mount it on box1, and then create an NFS link to wherever you mounted it.